# How to rename a file to have the same name and extension as another file in same directory

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to use the find command to edit files named "msf.txt" in many different sub-directories and I want it to take the same filename and extension as whatever file shares the same extension in it's directory. So as an example, let's pretend I'm inside one of the sub directories which has an msf.txt file and an msf-01.txt file. I want to rename msf.txt to msf-01.txt. I want to automate this across many sub-directories, but only do it in sub-directories that have the phrase "data" in the directory name. Can anyone provide some suggestions? I'd prefer to use something like find for this.

This is what the current directory looks like

```
main/
|--sub01    
    ├── data/
    │   ├── mgw.txt
    │   ├── mgw-01.txt
    ├── pictures/
    │   ├── bootstrap1.png
    │   └── bootstrap2.png
    └── extra/
        ├── stuff.txt

 |--sub02   
    ├── data/
    │   ├── mgw.txt
    │   ├── mgw-02.txt
    ├── pictures/
    │   ├── bootstrap1.png
    │   └── bootstrap2.png
    └── extra/
        ├── stuff.txt
```

This is what I want it to look like and the .txt files inside the data directories are meant to contain what was inside the mgw.txt files

```
main/
|--sub01    
    ├── data/
    │   ├── mgw-01.txt
    ├── pictures/
    │   ├── bootstrap.png
    │   └── bootstrap.png
    └── extra/
        ├── stuff.txt

 |--sub02   
    ├── data/
    │   ├── mgw-02.txt
    ├── pictures/
    │   ├── bootstrap1.png
    │   └── bootstrap2.png
    └── extra/
        ├── stuff.txt
```

Comment: I'm pretty confused here. Could you please edit your question, removing all extraneous information, and distilling the problem to its core? i.e. what is (a minimal version of) the current situation, and what is the expected version.

Comment: @Sparkhawk Okay I see what you mean. Just edited. Hopefully will be more clear

Comment: I'm still confused. Just show the literal directory structure, before and after.

Comment: @Sparhawk okay I added the directory structure

Comment: Thank you. So in the first sub-directory (`main/sub01/data/`), `mgw.txt` is renamed to `mgw-01.txt`. Presumably the `01` in this filename comes from `sub01`. Where does the original `mgw-01.txt` go? Is it just deleted?

Comment: I'd like to just move the original `mgw-01.txt` and all the files like it to a folder somewhere else instead of having them overwritten and removed

Comment: Sooo… these two trees aren't the before and after then? The "after" tree is actually not depicting the same main directory as "before"? If you want to move them "somewhere else", what is the logic for the files to move? It seems like some files are moved as is (`bootstrap.png`), others are moved with renaming (`mgw.txt`), and others are not moved at all (the original `mgw-01.txt`). Also, how can there be two `bootstrap.png` in the same directory?

Comment: they are the before and after. I missed the 1 and 2 in the bootstrap files. the after tree is what happens after you do the file renaming. The logic for keeping the original files is that I need a record of the old text files. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
would-do() print -r -- "$@"

for f (**/data/mgw.txt(N)) {
   others=($f:r-*.txt(N))
   if (($#others)); then
     would-do mkdir -p $f:h:h/backup &&
       would-do mv $others $f:h:h/backup/ &&
       would-do mv $f $others[1]
   fi
}
```

Change the `would-do` definition to `would-do() "$@"` to actually do it.

Comment: How does the backup of the old files work? Where do they get sent? Also, I'm guessing if I ever wanted to apply this to other directories with many (+5) levels of sub directories then the wildcard expansion `(**/data/mgw.txt(N)` would still work right? Or would I need more?